# ASP.NET RedirectToAction cambia el formato de los DateTimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mvc, web

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación basado en ASP.NET y me encuentro con un problema grande, y es que cuando hago un RedirectToAction en el controller, este me cambia el formato de los DateTimes en el Request de la clase ControllerBase.
Por ejemplo:

```
public class MyController:Controller{
    public ActionResult MyController(){
        return RedirectToAction("MyAction","MyController",{Fecha=DateTime.Now});
    }
    public ActionResult MyAction(DateTime date){
        ModelPrueba model = new ModelPrueba(){Fecha=date};
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Cuando se hace la llamada al método MyController, el Request.Params["Fecha"] es por ejemplo: 30/12/2021 (en formato dd/MM/yyyy).

Pero cuando se termina el RedirectToAction y se redirige la acción al método MyAction, Request.Params["Fecha"] cambia el formato a MM/dd/yyyy o sea 12/30/2021.

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe este error y si hay posibilidad de solucionarlo?

Es como RedirectToAction estuviera generando la QueryString del atributo Request de la clase ControllerBase con otro formato para las fechas

Comment: No es un error, debes especificar tu formato de fecha con [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Hola! He utilizado DateTime.ParseExact de esta forma: `CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; return RedirectToAction("MyAction","MyController",{Fecha=DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),"dd/MM/yyyy",provider)})` pero me sigue pasando lo mismo, sigue cambiando la fecha a formato MM/dd/yyyy, y he tenido que poner el formato dentro de ToString porque sino me lanzaba una excepción.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema se soluciona a la hora de reescribir la fecha, [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) solo lo convierte a un formato legible para C#, para mostrarlo como deseas solo necesitas realizar un `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

```
var fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),"MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    
//Partiendo de una fecha establecida
Console.WriteLine(fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")); // resultado:13/12/2021
//Con el mismo DateTime
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")); // resultado:13/12/2021
```